# Can the iPad3 emulate the iPad2 for app testing?

Tags: ipad, mobile

I have to develop an iPad app and I don't actually own an iPad, so I'm buying one now, ideally the iPad3 since it's the latest and greatest.  But probably many of the potential users of the app will be using their old iPad2 for a while.  And since the iPad3 is so much better than the iPad2 (double the resolution, for one thing), I'm concerned that if I test on the iPad3, I won't get any sense of what the app will be like on the iPad2.

So the question is: is it possible to do things like set the resolution to non-retina display settings and, in general, to make the iPad3 behave like the iPad2 for app testing purposes?

Comment: Grab an iPad 3 as the others have said... plus if you happen to have any extra cash, pick up a second hand original iPad - this way if it runs well on the iPad 1 as your non-retina device, then you know it'll be fine on the 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except of the resolution I don't see major difference between the iPad 2 and 3.
And the simulator can cover the resolution differences . As for the processor and speed etc' unless your app is a "memory monster" I don't see a big problem.

BTW you can always use services like [Test Flight](https://testflightapp.com) to get to users with other devices and run a beta.

Comment: Thanks.  Marking this as the answer because of the helpful link to Test Flight.  But the other answer from @RyanPoolos was very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to lower the resolution of your iPad 3 to that of an iPad 2 however performance wise it should work about the same or better on an iPad 2 in most cases since the extra iPad 3 horsepower is spent on the extra pixels.

Also I wouldn't worry about it too much. The iPad 3 has already sold more units than the iPad 2 in the short duration its been on the market. I think with a physical iPad 3 and the iOS simulator you should be able to reasonably ensure your app will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if everything was the same between them, but we definitely have issues with our web application between ipad2 and ipad3.  We had one work around that we had put in to get the ipad2 to work that later caused problems with the ipad3 came out.  Hopefully, things are better with app development rather than web applications.

Comment: Were the problems having to do with resolution and the retina display, or unrelated to that major difference between the devices?

Comment: No, it was more subtle than that.  We have a web app that shows an SSRS report in an iframe.  We use jquery load to determine when the report is done running so that we can resize the iframe to fit.  On ipad2, we have to have the iframe set as display:none and visibility:hidden to work correctly.  With the ipad3, this causes it to hang and it's required to be visible for it to work.  We speculate that ipad2 with the latest version of Safari would behave like the ipad3, but we don't have one set up like that for testing.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a browser issue, not an iPad issue as such.  And we thought browser incompatibilities were a thing of the dark, distant past.  It sounds like the sort of thing that jQuery should handle; have you submitted an issue there?

Comment: Agreed- seems like a browser issue.  The number of issues we had with the ipad certainly put me in mind of what we used to have to do to get IE working.